# PROJECT_LABEL CMake and XCocde

Tags: xcode, cmake

I am trying to change CMake target name folders in my IDE (Xcode). I read the documentation that says PROJECT_LABEL will do exactly this. It seems when I apply this property, it has no affect in Xcode. Is there another way to change a target name folders in Xcode or is just unsupported for this IDE?